# Deserialization error in localstack aws sdk sqs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, localstack

I have my expressjs app running and trying to push the messages(stringified object) into the queue(Local stack) with aws sdk v3.

```
awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue
```

> "@aws-sdk/client-sqs": "^3.428.0"

Getting this error,

^

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?xml vers"... is not valid JSON
> Deserialization error: to see the raw response, inspect the hidden
> field {error}.$response on this object.
> at JSON.parse

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const { SQS, SendMessageCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sqs");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Define the LocalStack SQS endpoint
const localStackEndpoint = "http://localhost:4566";

// Configure the SQS client
const sqs = new SQS({
  region: "us-east-1", // Specify any region (LocalStack doesn't enforce region constraints)
  endpoint: localStackEndpoint,
});

// Route to send a message to the SQS queue
app.post("/test", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Specify the URL of your LocalStack SQS queue
    const queueUrl = `${localStackEndpoint}/000000000000/my-queue`;

    // Define the message body
    const messageBody = "Hello, LocalStack!";

    // Create the SendMessageCommand
    const sendMessageCommand = new SendMessageCommand({
      QueueUrl: queueUrl,
      MessageBody: messageBody,
    });

    // Send the message
    const sendMessageResponse = await sqs.send(sendMessageCommand);

    console.log("Message sent successfully:", sendMessageResponse);

    res.send("Message sent successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending message:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error sending message");
  }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - '4566-4599:4566-4599'
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - PORT_WEB_UI=8080
    volumes:
      - '${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/var/lib/localstack'
```

Answer (score 0):

`@aws-sdk/client-sqs` library is using [AWS json protocol](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-json-faqs.html) for communication with Amazon SQS server, but it was not supported by `localstack` for SQS up-until recently (see this [PR](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/pull/8268))

Update your docker compose to work with latest localstack Docker image `localstack/localstack:3.1.0` should most likely solve the error that you see

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:3.1.0
    ports:
      - '4566-4599:4566-4599'
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - PORT_WEB_UI=8080
    volumes:
      - '${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/var/lib/localstack'
```